# Is DNA replication a serial or parallel process?

Tags: dna, dna-replication

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kK2zwjRV0M) entertainingly supplements this [3d animation](https://www.dnalc.org/resources/3d/04-mechanism-of-replication-advanced.html) of DNA strand replication. Does this process happen serially from the beginning to the end of a DNA strand (like having to unzip a six foot long zipper - example A below) or does the strand get chopped up into chunks, unzipped individually, replicated then brought back together (example B)?

[image]

I suspect the answer is case A. If so, is any phase of replication done in a parallel fashion? I would think something has to be (since it happens so fast and serial anything is typically very slow in comparison).

Comment: The DNA isn't cleaved, but replication can be initiated at multiple points on a chromosome and proceed in both directions. I'll elaborate on this later and post an answer in the future if no one else has. [This paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12206458) estimates that there are 10,000 to 100,000 replication origins in a human cell. This means that the average leading strand would be approximately 60,000 to 600,000 bp long.

Comment: [It's like having a zipper with multiple "pulls" along its length.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNlVk.jpg)

Comment: My personal opinion is that videos of this type and 3D animations are scientific poison. OK, for popularising science, but not a useful source of serious information. Rather than speculation, however intelligent, I suggest you consult text books that have been carefully written by experts, professionally illustrated, and edited by other experts. You can get access to older editions of some of these on NCBI Bookshelf: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/. If you search there for DNA replication you will find clear and comprehensive accounts to answer your question.

Comment: @canadianer, you're picture is perfect! That's the [answer](http://www.biomedicinaonline.com.br/2015/09/replicacao-do-dna.html)!

Comment: @David, thank you for the link. I'd like to add that popularizing science is good for science (which is antithetical to poison). Science without much interest or support doesn't get very far

Comment: Short hint: Yes while cell cycle in eukaryotic cell (many pieces of nuclear-DNA, each with many origin-of-replications) there are signaling/regulation mechanisms that ensures within a certain time period all-the nuclear DNA copies multiplied only upto certain times (ideally doubled) and chromatid numbers doesn't show anomaly. However *exceptions* are there... such as prokaryotes' plasmid DNA replication does not necessarily conforms with that of their nucleoid DNA... that is why plasmids replication called as semi-autonomous.

Comment: Your zipper-model in incomplete; because it shows a situation where origin of replication is at one terminus of linear DNA. That is atypical. Usually origins are found at inner portion(s), that cause replication bubble (containing 2 replication fork face to face). It is like a zipper track with 2-zipper opening from the same point. However this misinterpretation is very common among school-students.

Comment: @David Agree; ultramodern teaching-aids like powerpoints, animations, e-readers etc. are being mishandled too-much. They becomes useful only after I get the concept through 'backdated' slow method of boardwork, printed textbooks, notebook, paper and pencil. However the website tells it is "advanced" level; so it is not the basics lesson.

Comment: @canadianer Your link can't be accessed. Browser warns "the page is not working".

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Which one? They both work for me.

Comment: I think I made a mistake with my math. Should be 30,000 to 300,000?

Comment: @canadianer http://www.biomedicinaonline.com.br/2015/09/replicacao-do-dna.html

Comment: @AlwaysConfused I didn't post that… and I can access it fine.

Comment: @canadianer eh sorry it was pinged to you by zelusp. Maybe mistake due to i slept less for last few nights. Thanks however the link is not working from here [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzL2w.png) ; may be the site works within definite countries.